# How do I switch activities in Android SDK for Chromecast

Tags: android, sdk, chromecast

I have the standard Chromecast Sender application running. Here is the code I'm using to connect the chromecast, and go to the next activity:

**Find the Chromecast** Works great.

```
    // ===================
    // Configure Cast device discovery
    // ===================      
    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(
                    CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.app_id))).build();
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
```

**When I click the button to connect, switch to a new activity**

```
/**
 * Callback for MediaRouter events
 */
public class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");
        // Handle the user route selection.
        mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());

        launchReceiver();           

        // CONNECTION ESTABLISHED, SWITCH TO NEW ACTIVITY
        startActivity(new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); 

    }

}
```

**The problem is now on the MainActivity.class - I seem to have lost connection to Chromecast, although my icon is clearly marked as being connect**

Answer (score 0):

Your connection should be maintained at the application level (or through a singleton or service) so you don't run into issues when you change your activity. Using a tab layout is very restrictive approach. You can use [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) and that handles that for you.